# journalctl missing cron entries that show up in syslog

Tags: cron, syslog, systemd-journald

I have cron set up to log start (CMD) and end (END) of all cron jobs along with the process number (setting up cron to use `-L 11` option). All entries are showing up in `/var/log/syslog`, such as:

```
Aug 26 13:44:01 demo_xu64 CRON[40332]: (demo) CMD ([40335] /usr/bin/sudo tcpreplay -M 0.1 --preload-pcap -i ens38 /home/demo/pcap_files/p26-traffic.pcap #cyber_demo)
Aug 26 13:45:34 demo_xu64 CRON[40332]: (demo) END ([40335] /usr/bin/sudo tcpreplay -M 0.1 --preload-pcap -i ens38 /home/demo/pcap_files/p26-traffic.pcap #cyber_demo)
```

However, sometimes journcalctl doesn't log the END, such as `journalctl -u cron | grep 40335`, which only yields CMD:

```
Aug 26 13:44:01 demo_xu64 CRON[40332]: (demo) CMD ([40335] /usr/bin/sudo tcpreplay -M 0.1 --preload-pcap -i ens38 /home/demo/pcap_files/p26-traffic.pcap #cyber_demo)
```

I have tried setting `RateLimitIntervalSec=0` and `RateLimitBurst=0` in the `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` file as well as setting cron `-L` option to `15` (to log errors), but to no avail.

I can't understand why they would show up in `/var/log/syslog` but not the journalctl files.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!